# How to install chef-manage as add-on to chef-server supermarket cookbook

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am using the chef supermarket [chef-server cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-server). I am using chef-solo to bootstrap a chef-server in Vagrant through this cookbook. According to this cookbook's documentation, I can add a list value to the attribute default['chef-server']['addons']. I would like to add "manage" to that list so when I bootstrap chef-server through 'vagrant up', it also installs chef-manage.

In the Vagrant file's shell provisioner section, this command exists:

```
sudo chef-solo -o 'recipe[chef-server::default]'
```

What can I add to this command such that 'manage' is added to the attributes? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should create an attributes json file in VM (myfile.json):

```
{
  'chef-server': {
    'addons': %w{manage}
  } 
}
```

and pass it as a parameter to chef-solo:

```
sudo chef-solo -j myfile.json -o 'recipe[chef-server::default]'
```